# django charge users based on how many counties they want to access

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm building a web app,
basically I currently have 3 models ,
1- State: which represents all US states
2- County: which represents all counties with foreign key of state
3- Home: which represents all homes with foreign key of County

the app will show homes,
but users needs to subscribe for certain counties (the counties prices can vary)
the goal is : when users subscribe to certain counties they can see the related "Homes" to these counties

I'm not sure how should I represent these relations between users, subscriptions and how to connect it to County model I have.
and how to make a view for the user to add new counties.

Thank you.

Update (My models):

```
class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_name

class County(models.Model):
    county_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.county_name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("county_name", "state")
        verbose_name_plural = 'Counties'

class Home(models.Model):
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    county = models.ForeignKey(County, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    sqft = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    home_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    geom = models.PointField()

    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}, {}'.format(self.street_address, self.city, self.county.state.state_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Home'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Homes'

    @property
    def state_county(self):
        return f'{self.county.county_name}_{self.state}'

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self.county.state.state_name
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have tried so far?

Comment: For the subscriptions I didn't do anything before asking.

Comment: Usually its a good idea do show that you have tried something. Looks like you are asking other to do the work for you. But thas fine, I will gave you an example and you can explore from that point.

Comment: sorry if it looks like I didn't try, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: let me share my current models at least then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic idea, you should evaluate from this point.

```
class State(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class County(models.Model)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Home(models.Model)
    county= models.ForeignKey(County)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Subscription(models.Model)
    county = models.ForeignKey(County)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Basically, you can then charge your user per County (observe that one can have more than one County subscription)

Another aproach would be to use a hierarchy to have State>County>Home, on a MPTT, but maybe its not what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot Walucas your example is really helpful.
@borut made county as many to many relationship ,
do you think that's better ?
or should I stick to foreign key,
to be honest I was thinking of foreign key as well.

Comment: @Ibrahim I think ForeignKey is easier to control the subscription, basically you will have one ID per subscription. If you add a Start/End date you will control WHEN the user subscribed and unsubscribed. With the many-to-many you will not have the control at that level. Usually thats a good idea, to control these start/end dates.

Comment: I just wrote about the dates to borut,
you're thinking same as I.

Comment: so the foreign key is easier but then the subscription won't be flexible to add counties in the middle of the month , yes ?

Comment: I just read Borut's answer what he is saying is that with one subs you can have the dates on the subs, which is a good thing. You can have both ways in both models, your decision needs to be whats the common scenario on your app. If in one button hit the user can have three counties in one subscription, then go with Borut's. But if the user will select one, then another, then another, with some timelapse between, then consider mine. Also have in mind that if you want to do some "offers", like 3 counties combo, Borut's may be easier to handle, since you can link that to the combo.

Comment: thanks for the explanation ,
I'll stick to Foreign Keys since it will deal with each county separately,
and i'm not considering any combinations at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add ManyToMany `County` relationship field in the `Subscriptions` model and then you would query subscribed county and filter `Home`.

Something in the sense of:

```
class County(models.Model):

    county = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Home(models.Model):

    county = models.ForeignKey(County, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Subscription(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeingKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    county = models.ManyToMany(County)
```

Then you'd query subscriptions and filter based on that.

```
subscriptions = Subscription.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('county', flat=True)
homes = Home.objects.filter(county_id__in=subscriptions)
```

You could further improved that with [models Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) on Subscription to avoid filtering `user` every time with something like:

```
class SubscriptionManager(models.Manager):
    def user_subscriptions(self, user):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=user)

class Subscription(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeingKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    county = models.ManyToMany(County)

    objects = SubscriptionManager()
```

and then filter either with:

```
subscriptions = Subscription.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('county', flat=True)
```

or

```
subscriptions = Subscription.objects.user_subscriptions(request.user).values_list('county', flat=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example ,
but why do you think we should use many to many relationship for the county ?

Comment: Because user will be subscribed to many counties with one subscription and with foreign key they won't be able to subscribe to many counties, but just one.

Comment: I believe we should add start and end dates for subscriptions, and this way each county can be charged separately , yes ?

Comment: This doesn't really influence the decision between foreign key and many-to-many. Many-to-many doesn't take anything from foreign key, but adds a possibility to have multiple counties in one subscription. You can still have one subscription for three counties from January to May and another subscription for just one county from February to May. Imagine managing user's subscription to 47 counties with same starting and ending dates. It's one row in the Subscription table vs. 47 rows.

Comment: make sense ,thanks,
so for managing subscription , should I run a daily process to check if the subscription is ended or not then disable it,
or should I simply do a query set that will filter subscriptions with counties end date larger than today ?

Comment: I guess you could use model Manager for that; to filter active subscriptions. In one of many projects I added a boolean subscription status field to subscription model and wrote a middleware that checked subscription status on every request and changed it False when it ran out. Then I used model manager to filter based on that boolean field. Maybe that's a bit excessive, but my subscriptions were DateTime, not just Date. With just Date you could set up a cron job on a daily basis, when server is the least busy.